# Is there a way to temporarily disable the mouseover event of an embedded video?

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-events

I am using the jQuery resizable [plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/) to allow  users to resize an embedded video. The video is a child of a div which is getting resized. Here is a fiddle of the basics http://jsfiddle.net/jrzNW/1/.

It works fine until the mouse hovers over the the video itself and then the resizing stops until the mouse moves off the video. I tried setting a div to `show()` when the click event begins but that created more problems then solutions. If someone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, have you tried something like this?

```
$('#video').on('mouseover', function() { return false; });
```

That should abort any other things registered for that event. See [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> Returning false from an event handler will automatically call `event.stopPropagation()`
>   and `event.preventDefault()`. A false value can also be passed for the handler as a
>   shorthand for `function(){ return false; }`. So, `$("a.disabled").on("click", false);`
>   attaches an event handler to all links with class "disabled" that prevents them from being
>   followed when they are clicked and also stops the event from bubbling.

Comment: is there another way. I tried several variations of that code over the past few hours and it does not seem to solve the problem.(updated fiddle of what I have been trying http://jsfiddle.net/jrzNW/2/)       Could it be because the video is embedded on another site?

Comment: You seem to be embedding with an `<iframe>`... You'd have to trigger the event in the context of that frame... something like: `$('#video', $('#iframe')).on('mouseover', ...)`